# What's a good site for human body props resourcing?

Tags: resource-recommendations, comics

I'm trying to improve comics style, and I'm looking for a good resource where I can find human body and/or comics layouts, scene building, etc. Is there a good place for these? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean mannequins, or human anatomy reference photos?

Comment: Finding human 'anatomy' photos online is rather trivial. Just turn of safe search in google.

Comment: I know, right? I always thought Masamune Shirow just threw a porno into his VHS for reference and inspiration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you're looking for?
[Human body reference photos](http://www.fineart.sk/) (warning, there are nudes)

Comment: great, I liked specialy of Andrew Loomis Anathomy Books...